# Nested Relations showing not enough values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently learning about nested-relational structures within SQL Plus and I am trying to nest orders and customer details within a customer account, but whenever I run the following script I get the error `ORA-00947: not enough values` at `INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('John Smith','90210'` and it doesn't recognise the rest of the values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Create Type ORDERS as Object (
    ORDER_NO    CHAR(5), 
    ORDER_DATE  DATE, 
    TOTAL       NUMBER)
/

Create Type ORDER_TAB as Table of ORDERS
/


Create Type CONTACT as Object (
    STREET  VARCHAR(20),
    CITY    VARCHAR(15),
    EMAIL   VARCHAR(30),
    PHONE   VARCHAR(12))
/

Create Type CONTACT_Tab as Table of CONTACT
/

DROP Table CUSTOMER cascade constraints PURGE
/

Create Table CUSTOMER (
    NAME         VARCHAR(20),
    CUST_ID      CHAR(5),
    CUST_DETAILS CONTACT_TAB,
    CUST_ORDER   ORDER_TAB)
    Nested Table CUST_DETAILS Store As CONTACT_DETAILS
    Nested Table CUST_ORDER Store As ORDER_DETAILS
/

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES ('John Smith', '90210',
        CONTACT_TAB(CONTACT ('Buckingham Palace', 'London', 
                     'john.smith@gmail.com', '0111111111'),
        ORDER_TAB(ORDERS ('54321', TO_DATE('01-01-2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 124),
        ORDERS ('76421', TO_DATE('06-08-2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 31),
        ORDERS ('18784', TO_DATE('07-18-2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 33))
    ))
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you format queries properly, you could figure out what's wrong. It was just a missing parentheses issue. This query should work.

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (
     NAME
    ,CUST_ID
    ,CUST_DETAILS
    ,CUST_ORDER
    )
VALUES (
    'John Smith'
    ,'90210'
    ,CONTACT_TAB(CONTACT('Buckingham Palace', 'London', 'john.smith@gmail.com', '0111111111'))
    ,ORDER_TAB(ORDERS('54321', TO_DATE('01-01-2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 124)
    ,ORDERS('76421', TO_DATE('06-08-2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 31)
    ,ORDERS('18784', TO_DATE('07-18-2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 33)
    ) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been staring at this for hours and couldn't see my problem. I feel like a dunce now it appears so obvious!